# Unsupported abi version

Tags: cleos, transactions, testnet

I am making an offline transaction. I am providing the API with the following parameters as an object:

```
rpc: new JsonRpc('https://jungle.eos.dfuse.io/', { fetch }),
signatureProvider: new JsSignatureProvider(this.privateKeys),
textDecoder: new TextDecoder(),
textEncoder: new TextEncoder(),
chainId: 'e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473',
abiProvider, authorityProvider: Promise.resolve(this.privateKeys)
```

I am fetching the abi from `/get_raw_abi`. Using `JSON.stringify()` to convert it into a string, then converting it to `base64` using `buffer`, then converting that to binary by `base64ToBinary`

I am saving the result as follows:

```
const result = await this.eosApi.transact({
    actions: [createAccount, buyRam, delegateBw],
    ref_block_num: refBlockNum,
    ref_block_prefix: RefBlockPrefix,
    expiration: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30 * 60000)
    }, {
    broadcast: false, sign: true
})
```

I am getting the error: `Error: fetching abi for eosio: Unsupported abi version`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to help you out if you'll post the definitions of `createAccount`, `buyRam`, `delegateBw` & `abiProvider` and tell us what eosjs version you're using.  :)

***Post comment edit:***
Found the issue - eosjs's `JsonRpc` currently messes things up when being instantiated with an endpoint with a trailing forward slash, just use `https://jungle.eos.dfuse.io` instead of `https://jungle.eos.dfuse.io/`.

P.S. - I was about to open a pull request for eosjs to fix this, but then I saw they already fixed it in the `develop` branch - https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/develop/src/eosjs-jsonrpc.ts#L33 (damn...)

Comment: I'm using eosjs version 20.0.0
The createAccount, buyRam and delegateBw are:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hali241997/4bf83b3a7ee7c117f8efb72479bf753c

Replace the `account` variable with any junglenet account

Comment: @HasnainAli I found the issue! Check out the answer edit.